# How can I say when an uncountable noun coordinates with a countable noun?

Tags: articles

> These are all water.

> Coral reefs are important place for them.

or

> These is all water.

> Coral reefs is important place.

or do such sentences not make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb must always agree in number with the subject:

- These are …
- Coral reefs are …

The object complement not agreeing with the subject may make this seem a bit odd, but it doesn’t affect the verb at all.

Comment: ...and _Coral reefs are important_ **places**.